# C# Calling a function but string is null

Tags: c#

I am trying to check a value of string.

However sometimes the string may contain a null value.

```
 Boolean checkValue =  segment.CheckStringValue(stringValue)
```

When this happens then I get the following error `nullreferenceexception was unhandled`

Is there a way to avoid this from happening?

Comment: I'm presuming either segment is null or stringValue is null.. Is the exception within the method CheckStringValue or not?

Comment: the `segment` object could be null, too!

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
Boolean checkValue =  segment.CheckStringValue(stringValue);
```

with

```
Boolean checkValue =  segment.CheckStringValue(stringValue ?? String.Empty);
```

or handle a null value within your method `if (value == null)` ...

Comment: The method title `CheckStringValue` would lead me to believe it would be better to have a check inside the method, Not much to be gained by checking against a different string. (Throwing the error might actually be the better thing to do)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
String stringCheck = "";
if(stringValue != null
  stringCheck=stringValue;
Boolean checkValue =  segment.CheckStringValue(stringCheck);
```